# bootstrap or javascript validation for select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Bootstrap or Javascript and I am facing the problem of dropdown select validation. I have retrieved the list items from database dynamically and want to set validation for it, that it should be selected compulsory, so could you please help me to do that?? Thanks in advance!!

```
$(function () {
    $("#save").click(function () {
        var optionTypeId = $("#optionTypeId");

        if (optionTypeId.val() == '-') {
            //If the "Please Select" option is selected display error.
            alert("Please select an option!");
           return false;
        }           
             return true;


    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show your dropdown html code

Comment: What's the problem with the current code?

Answer (score 3):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var select = $('#test_select'),
        save_btn = $('#save_btn');

    save_btn.on('click',function(e){
        if(select.length){
           if(select.val() === '') alert('select smth');
           else console.log('select val ='+select.val());
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select id="test_select">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
  
<button id="save_btn">SAVE</button>
  
</body>
</html>
```